# How do I change the value of a persisted property in an MSI during a Modify operation?

Tags: windows-installer

I have an MSI that I've created.  In that MSI, I have a persisted property that the user has filled in during the initial installation of the application, using a custom dialog box.  When the install is run again, and the user selects to Modify the installation, the values initially entered appear as they should.

However, if the user changes the value, those values are not being persisted so that the 2nd time the user elects to modify the application, the 2nd set of values are not being shown, but the first set of values are.

Is it possible to change a persisted property, or is that always going to be the data entered during the install?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how you are persisting your Properties. If you are using a Registry key then you need to make the Component state to be Install again.

Comment: I am using a Registry key.  Is there an easy way to do that?  I took your answer and found a thread in the WIX toolset group about using REINSTALL and a Custom Action, but it seemed a bit convoluted, probably since I don't use WIX, so I'm hoping for an easier solution. :)